# ASP .NET Core Authorization Handler: Get single failing requirement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

Assuming a policy `SomePolicy` contains list of `IAuthorizationRequirement` added as such:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SomePolicy", policy =>
        {
            policy.AddRequirements(new FooRequirement());
            policy.AddRequirements(new BarRequirement());
            policy.AddRequirements(new YetAnotherRequirement());
        });
});
```

Upon execution of the policy, I would like to know which of the requirement failed and prevent the check of the remaining requirements.

Looking up what I can do with the API, it appears that after execution of the policy, the only thing I can do is retrieve the list of failed requirements.

```
var authorizationResult = _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(this.User, ressource, "SomePolicy");
var failedRequirements = authorizationResult.Result.Failure.FailedRequirements
```

Is a policy based approach not suited for what I am trying to achieve ?
Should I create dedicated policy for each of the requirement ?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Each requirement needs to have `context.Succeed(requirement)` called by one of the handlers, and no `context.Failed()` calls by any handler.

[InvokeHandlersAfterFailure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationoptions.invokehandlersafterfailure?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is a way to short-circuit handler invocations for a particular requirement once `context.Failed()` has been called, but that isn't very useful IMO.

I'm trying to get short-circuit evaluation by adding an extension method to `IAuthorizationService`:

```
public static async Task<AuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAnyAsync(this IAuthorizationService service, ClaimsPrincipal user,
    object? resource, params IAuthorizationRequirement[] requirements)
{
    AuthorizationResult? result = null;
    foreach (var requirement in requirements)
    {
        result = await service.AuthorizeAsync(user, resource, requirement);
        if (result.Succeeded || result.Failure.FailCalled)
            return result;
    }
    return result!;
}
```